# Fullcalendar, listDay view problems with first time to show

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and I want to see events in **listDay** only from **6am to 6am** (first time must be 6am). In agendaView I have used scrollTime and minTime options.

This is an example image:

[image: example image]

> Is there some native setting options for listDay to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do this, how will the user know that some events are excluded? When you use minTime with a visible time axis, it's clear that it starts at 6am and that anything before that is not going to be shown. But here it isn't clear. Users could be confused. Besides, if you do have some events before that time, why would you want to hide them? Anyway, all the settings which are specific to list views are documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view

Comment: I know, the reason is that customer want... He is print day to day (listDay) and events before 6am is redudant for him. 

Target is show events from 6am to 6am (next day) in one day. So he see redudant events in previous days. I dont know if its possible to show events after midnight to one day (it has no logic)... 

My solution is:
I will create custom output via datatables maybe...

Comment: you could maybe use the `eventRender` callback in fullCalendar to check the time on each event and return `false` if the time is outside your desired zone, then it will not be displayed.